# Data Structure for Storing Location and Time

Tags: database, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking for a data structure that can store points containing position data ((x, y), (latitude, longitude), etc.) and time data. I was planning on using a 3 dimensional KD-Tree but I’m running into problems because of the time data. Since points are added as they come in, and the time almost always increases, the points are being added almost linearly (to the right of the previous one).

I want to be able to perform insertions, deletions, and nearest neighbor queries on the data.

Comment: would a struct to hold those coordinates and "etc" be viable then just store those structs in an array. I would not spend too much time worrying about a data structure if your sets are small

Comment: A struct would be viable to hold those coordinates but the set is very large.

Comment: so you want something that can lookup each structs data without having to use a brute force approach i assume?

Comment: Yeah. Points are expected to come in overtime and keep being added.

Comment: what about a hashmap?

Comment: How would I perform nearest neighbor queries?

Comment: maybe you can use the hash function in a way that generates a hash based on the size of the struct and the size of the hashmap itself. Sure way is to use something called linear/quadratic probing

Comment: Interesting. Maybe there is a way to generate a hash based on longitude and latitude and time such that points that are close in the real-world have nearby hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical term is [Spatiotemporal database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatiotemporal_database), that should allow you to look up related research and algorithms.

To avoid the problem with the kd-tree, some kd-trees have a rebalance() function that may be helpful.
Also, how about using a [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R*-tree) (self balancing) or a [PH-Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH-tree) (does not require rebalancing and depths is inherently limited to 64; disclaimer: self advertisement)?